# Redirect reverse-proxy with SNI and subdomain

Tags: ssl, nginx, subdomain, sni

I have one machine with a loadbalancer, nginx in a container and I want to redirect 2 domains to one server throught 443, this works.
But when I add the server c with a subdomain as a ssl_preread_server_name 
it doesn't work. (the first still working)

I tried with regex, I searched and I didn't found anything related to ssl_preread and subdomains

```
map $ssl_preread_server_name $name {
    *.my.domain.com c;
    a.another.domain.com a;
    b.another.domain.com b;
}

upstream a {
    server "ip1:443" max_fails=2 fail_timeout=30s;
}

upstream b {
    server "ip1:443" max_fails=2 fail_timeout=30s;
}

upstream c {
    server "ip2:33390" max_fails=2 fail_timeout=30s;
}

log_format stream_routing '$remote_addr [$time_local] '
                          'with SNI name "$ssl_preread_server_name" '
                          'proxying to "$name" '
                          '$protocol $status $bytes_sent $bytes_received '
                          '$session_time';

server {
    listen 443;
    ssl_preread on;
    proxy_pass $name;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/stream_443.log stream_routing;
}
```

when I add the server c with a subdomain as a ssl_preread_server_name 
the error is: 
`*3 no host in upstream ""`

when I curl the server should redirect to the upstream c

Comment: You need to add the `hostnames` keyword to use `*.example.com` style names in the `map` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_map_module.html#map) for details.

Comment: Yes!!! thank you!!!

`map $ssl_preread_server_name $name {
   hostnames;
    *.my.domain.com c;
    a.another.domain.com a;
    b.another.domain.com b;
}`